# Iterating through JSON to populate map

Tags: javascript, html, json, for-loop, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to iterate through a JSON file and put relevant data inside my markers variable. through each iteration markers should change, however I am stuck. Does anyone know how to do this or how I could?

**This is a smaller version of my JSON:**

```
{"properties": 
[{"latitude":"53.542637347578406","longitude":"-113.51709427725768",
"account":"1061985","value":"$500"},
{"latitude":"53.5384925504052","longitude":"-113.520385218556",
"account":"1248558","value":"$500"}]}
```

**This is my JavaScript Code:**

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        mapId: "8e0a97af9386fef",
        center: {lat: 53.55204130841203, lng: -113.49684664653883},
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeControl: false,
    });
    const markers = [
        [
            "Assessed",
            53.432556261744296,
            -113.61359034412152,
            "house-svgrepo-com.svg",
            40,
            41
        ]
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        const currMarker = markers[i];
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: currMarker[1], lng: currMarker[2]},
            map,
            title: currMarker[0],
            icon: {
                url: currMarker[3],
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(currMarker[4], currMarker[5])

            },
//            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
    }
}
```

What im trying to do here is populate `const markers` with latitude, longitude, and assessed value from the JSON.
So: "Assessed" will turn into JSON "value"

**This is the HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Edmonton Property Assessments</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Map View</h1>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <script
          async
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=UR_KEY&callback=initMap">   
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem are you having? How are you trying to add markers from the posted JSON?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I'm having problems creating a for loop that changes `const markers` into the approriate values from the JSON that way i can populate my map with markers. @geocodezip

Comment: Do you want the icons to be determined by data in the JSON file? If so, what information determines the icon?  [jsfiddle that displays your posted json as default markers](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uz4rpa82/)  What do you mean by '"Assessed" will turn into JSON "value"'?

Comment: hey sorry no the values in `const markers` are just to be populated with "value" from JSON in the place of "assessed", "latitude" from JSON in the place of the 53.432556261744296 and "longitude" from JSON in place of the -113.61359034412152.

Comment: The icons will be kept the same and so will the sizes. @geocodezip

Comment: What do you mean by "each iteration markers should change" then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243672/discussion-between-misfit-and-geocodezip).

Answer (score 0):

Since the parsed value of that file's content will only be available inside fetch's resolution, you could move any following logic to be inside the final `then`.

However, since `initMap` is invoked (as the library's loaded callback) without expecting any return value, you can change it's declaration to be `async` without worrying about breaking other parts.

Inside an async function you could do

```
async function initMap() {
   const map=new google.maps.Map(etc etc)
   const contents = await fetch(',/src/mapview/properties.json')
                                  .then(res=>res.json())
  // the rest of your logic
}
```

and get that file's content, as an object. Make sure you use the public url to that json. The relative path would work, sure, under the right circumstances, but absolute urls will make your life much easier when dealing with locally stored files whose location is known beforehand.

At this point, `contents.properties` holds:

```
[
 {
  "latitude":"53.542637347578406",
  "longitude":"-113.51709427725768",
  "account":"1061985",
  "value":"$500"
 },
 {
  "latitude":"53.5384925504052",
  "longitude":"-113.520385218556",
  "account":"1248558",
  "value":"$500"
 }
]
```

Which you would traverse to actually print your markers

```
let propertyMarkers=[]
for(let property_entry of contents.properties) {
  let {latitude, longitude, ...markerValues} = property_entry
  propertyMarkers.push(
     new google.maps.Marker({
        position:{
          lat:Number(latitude), 
          lng: Number(longitude)
        },
        map 
     })
  )
}
```

I'm not just creating the markers but also storing them in an array. Not mandatory for this example but it will allow you to operate on them further on.

Please note I'm casting your numeric coordinates to actual numbers. Since I don't know how are you planning to use other properties, or populate missing ones (like the icon svg name) I'm just populating `markerValues` with anything that's not latitude and longitude. Use it as you see fit.

Final caveat: I'm not handling errors.

Post response caveat: Your comments and your question point in different directions. You need to

1. handle asynchronous data retrieval
2. map the entries array into your a suitable structure of choice
3. create markers from that known structure

Start by making sure I're putting entry markers on the map, before throwing additional logic to the mix.

Comment: I tried using this method but it wont work @ffflabs